# Why is My MYSQLI DELETE set on interval function not running

Tags: php, mysql

I have search and tried all codes I could find to try to delete certain rows based on an 8hr interval from current time but it is not working. I put it in the header and in other pages. here is my code:

```
`date_default_timezone_set('Country/City');
if (isset($_SESSION["login"])) {
    $display = $_SESSION["login"];
    $day_nudge = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM nudges WHERE nudge_time < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -8 HOUR)");
}`
```

I have also tried other ways such as:

```
DELETE FROM nudges
WHERE nudge_time < (NOW() - INTERVAL 8 HOUR)

DELETE FROM nudges
WHERE nudge_time < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 8 HOUR)
```

these all worked on local host but now its on my server it does not execute.

Comment: do you know your code even gets to the querry part, a lot could happen before there.

Comment: i have other queries in the same if statement that run fine here is the full code all runs fine except the delete  `include ( "./inc/connect.php" ); session_start(); ob_start(); date_default_timezone_set('Country/City'); if (isset($_SESSION["login"])) { $display = $_SESSION["login"]; $near = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE displaynm='$display' "); $nearb = mysqli_fetch_assoc($near); $near = $nearb['location']; $nearl = explode(',',trim($near)); $day_nudge = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM nudges WHERE nudge_time < DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -8 HOUR)"); $display = ""; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After taking a break and playing with some other bugs... I came back and just thought I would try something and it worked for me, thought I would post it here incase anyone else may find it useful.

```html
$datnudge = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-8 hour'));
$day_nudge = mysqli_query($conn,"DELETE FROM nudges WHERE nudge_time <= '$datnudge'");
```

Comment: is your database server time different than your web server time?

Comment: I thought that may have been the issue but I changed my server to suit but was still not working, I am having a similar issue with another one of my timers slightly different but if i cant get it to work that is for another question haha